# JQuery, Passing Parameters

Tags: jquery, parameters

I'm working with some very basic jquery code and would like to condense what I've done into one function with passed parameters.

I have a few of these:

```
$(".about").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","_img/nav/about_over.gif");
        }, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","_img/nav/about_off.gif");
});


$(".artists").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","_img/nav/artists_over.gif");
        }, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","_img/nav/artists_on.gif");
});


$(".help").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","_img/nav/help_over.gif");
        }, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","_img/nav/help_off.gif");
});
```

But would obviously like to pass the the title of the image ("about", artists", "help") so that I could cut down on repeated code.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Ronnie

Answer (score 4):

```
function hover(img) {
    $("."+img).hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","_img/nav/"+img+"_over.gif");
       }, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","_img/nav/"+img+"_off.gif");
    });
}
```

Comment: Need to change `$(class_name)` to `$("." + class_name)`

Comment: This is just changing the src attribute twice... so effectively rendering the first statement useless.  You need to use a call back function for the _off.gif.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could something like this:

```
function ElementHover(class_name, src_over, src_off) {
   $("."+class_name+"").hover(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", src_over);
      }, function() {
      $(this).attr("src", src_off);
   });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function HoverPic(name){
    $("."+name).hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","_img/nav/"+name+"_over.gif");
            }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","_img/nav/"+name+"_off.gif");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on with the second function in the hover function, but you can do something like this:

```
$(".about .artists .help").hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','_img/nav/' + $(this).attr('class') + '_over.gif')
});
```

you can apply the same principle to your on/off gifs too.

Comment: I used this one, but I fixed it by changing

$(".about .artists .help")

to 

$(".about, .artists, .help")

Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: Then select this as your answer.