# jQuery function with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, tooltip

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to realize a very simple tooltip just to learn how jQuery works.

After googling this is what I did:
**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#foo1").mouseover(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - $("#container").offset().left;
        var y = e.pageY - $("#container").offset().top;
        $('#div1').css({'top':y,'left':x}).show();
    });

    $("#foo1").mousemove(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - $("#container").offset().left;
        var y = e.pageY - $("#container").offset().top;
        $('#div1').css({'top':y,'left':x});
    });

    $("#foo1").mouseout(function(){
        $('#div1').hide();
    });

})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 200px; border: 1px black solid; position: relative;">
    Something here
</div>
<div id="container" style="width: 300px; border: 1px black solid; position: relative;">
    <a id="foo1" href="javascript:void(0);">[hover me]</a>
    <div id="div1" class="tt">Content goes here.</div>
    <a id="foo2" href="javascript:void(0);">[hover me too!]</a>
    <div id="div2" class="tt">I'm not working :(</div>
</div>
```

I used `var x = e.pageX - $("#container").offset().left;` because I had problems when `#div1` was inside a div with `position: relative;`

Everything works, but what if I add other links?

I would like to pass `#foo1` and `#div1` (and eventually `#container`, but actually I really don't need it) as parameters but the fact is that I have absolutely no idea on how to do this.

I tried searching here, I found this: [JQuery, Passing Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202551/jquery-passing-parameters)

So I think that maybe I can do something like:

```
function doStuff(param1, param2) {
    $(param1).mouseover(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - $("#container").offset().left;
        var y = e.pageY - $("#container").offset().top;
        $(param2).css({'top':y,'left':x}).show();
    });
    //etc etc
}
```

But I wouldn't know how to recall this function in HTML: in javascript I would have done something like `onmouseover="doStuff('foo1', 'div1')"`, but I don't really know what to do with jQuery :|

**EDIT:**

This is the code that generates the divs:

```
foreach ($colors_array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<div id='foo" . $key . "'>";
    // something else
    // according to some condition, I will decide whether to
    // call or not the function doStuff for this div.
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: How about using child-selectors on `$(this)` instead of giving every element a unique ID?

Comment: have a look at [jQuery.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @mercsen: you mean this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Code using $ as usual goes here.
});` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution, find element next to a having **tt** class :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".tooltipped").mouseover(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - $("#container").offset().left;
        var y = e.pageY - $("#container").offset().top;
        $(this).next('.tt').css({'top':y,'left':x}).show();
    });

    $(".tooltipped").mousemove(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - $("#container").offset().left;
        var y = e.pageY - $("#container").offset().top;
        $(this).next('.tt').css({'top':y,'left':x});
    });

    $(".tooltipped").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).next('.tt').hide();
    });

})
```

Your html :

```
<div id="container" style="width: 300px; border: 1px black solid; position: relative;">
    <a id="foo1" class="tooltipped" href="javascript:void(0);">[hover me]</a>
    <div id="div1" class="tt">Content goes here.</div>
    <a id="foo2" class="tooltipped" href="javascript:void(0);">[hover me too!]</a>
    <div id="div2" class="tt">I'm not working :(</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm but what if I have to choose whether to show or not the tooltip?
I've edited my answer, please take a look :)

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want to do, but by putting tooltipped class, you should be able to show the tooltip only on thoses links.

Comment: Omg this was so trivial that I didn't thought about it!
Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about the following: (assumes that you'll add class="active" to the elements you'd like to have hover effect + dynamic div is next to the a element)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".active").each(function(index, value){
    $(this).mouseover(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - $("#container").offset().left;
        var y = e.pageY - $("#container").offset().top;
        $(this).next().css({'top':y,'left':x}).show();                        
    });

    $(this).mousemove(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - $("#container").offset().left;
        var y = e.pageY - $("#container").offset().top;
        $(this).next().css({'top':y,'left':x});
    });

        $(this).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).next().hide();
    });
});
```

})

Sample HTML code:

```
<div style="width: 200px; border: 1px black solid; position: relative;">
    Something here
</div>
<div id="container" style="width: 300px; border: 1px black solid; position: relative;">
    <a id="foo1" class="active" href="javascript:void(0);">[hover me]</a>
    <div id="div1" class="tt">Content goes here.</div>
    <a id="foo2" href="javascript:void(0);">[hover me too!]</a>
    <div id="div2" class="tt">I'm not working :(</div>
    <a id="foo3" class="active" href="javascript:void(0);">[hover me too 3!]</a>
    <div id="div3" class="tt">I'm not working :(</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have what you need. You've confused yourself with your function name:

```
function setUpHandlers(param1, param2) {
    $(param1).mouseover(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - $("#container").offset().left;
        var y = e.pageY - $("#container").offset().top;
        $(param2).css({'top':y,'left':x}).show();
    });
    //etc etc
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Ok, now set them up once
    setUpHandlers('#foo1', '#div1');
    setUpHandlers('#foo2', '#div2');
});
```

Comment: mmm maybe I forgot to say that `#fooX` are dynamically generated... I don't know their actual names :(